# Parsing a datetime string with timezone in PHP

Tags: php, timezone

I have a string in this format: `2013-07-31T19:20:30.45-07:00` and I want to parse it so that I can, for example, say what day of the week it is. But I'm struggling to cope with the timezone offset. If I do `date_parse("2013-07-31T19:20:30.45-07:00")` then I end up with something like this:

```
array(15) {
  ["year"]=> int(2013)
  ["month"]=> int(7)
  ["day"]=> int(31)
  ["hour"]=> int(19)
  ["minute"]=> int(20)
  ["second"]=> int(30)
  ["fraction"]=> float(0.45)
  ["warning_count"]=> int(0)
  ["warnings"]=> array(0) { }
  ["error_count"]=> int(0)
  ["errors"]=> array(0) { }
  ["is_localtime"]=> bool(true)
  ["zone_type"]=> int(1)
  ["zone"]=> int(420)
  ["is_dst"]=> bool(false)
}
```

It's done something with the timezone, but what do I do with `420` if I want to, for example, show information about the timezone?

In case it matters, I have previously set my default timezone using `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')`.

**UPDATE:** If the string has a positive timezone, eg `2013-07-31T19:20:30.45+07:00` then the last part of the `date_parse()` output is:

```
  ["is_localtime"]=> bool(true)
  ["zone_type"]=> int(1)
  ["zone"]=> int(-420)
  ["is_dst"]=> bool(false)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

420 is zone in minutes.

> 420/60 = 7
>
> I want to parse it so that I can, for example, say what day of the
> week it is.

If you want to know what day of the week it is, you have many options. For example you can use date and mktime-functions:

```
$parsed = date_parse("2013-07-31T19:20:30.45-07:00");
$unix_timestamp = mktime($parsed['hour'], 0, 0, $parsed['month'], $parsed['day'], $parsed['year'], (int)$parsed['is_dst']);

echo date('l', $unix_timestamp);
```

So you want to show the information about timezone? You can get the time zone name by using `timezone_name_from_abbr` function:

```
$name = timezone_name_from_abbr("", -1*$parsed['zone']*60, false); // NB: Offset in seconds! 
var_dump($name);

$timezone = new DateTimezone($name); 
var_dump($timezone);
```

Comment: I hadn't even clocked that the zone might be minutes! I've added an example with positive timezone... It seems to me like the `zone` is the opposite of what I'd expect...?

Comment: Ok, you can forget the zone_type-field in this case. Time zone offset can be 15, 30 or 60 minutes.

Comment: Great, thank you! It's been ages since I've done much PHP and I'd managed to largely avoid timezones when I was last doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
2013-07-31T19:20:30.45-07:00
^ y-m-d    ^ time      ^ timezone offset
```

I'm guessing the timezone is `-7 hours` from UTC.

Keep in mind that some countries have half-hour timezones, or even minute timezones. This is probably why you get the timezone in minutes.

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't even realised that the `420` was minutes!